# Kotlin MVVM firestore callbackFlow: Stuck with IMPLICIT TYPE CASTING to ANY?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm, callback

I am new to mobile development and I have been following advices from Alex Mamo's lecture and so far it has proven to be working. Now as I am trying to implement new things and fetch data, from one solution to another there are differences that seem to be incompatible.

I have Firebase Auth on this app and now I am trying to go and fetch data from Firestore and I get an IMPLICIT TYPE CASTING to ANY?

[image]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
override fun getBudgetsFromFireStore() = callbackFlow {
    val snapListener = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).orderBy("name").whereIn("id", listOf("I91xw6MUBpofeCmYYUCz"))
        .addSnapshotListener { snap, e ->
        val res = if (snap != null) {
            val budgets = snap.toObjects(SettingBudget::class.java)
            Success(budgets)
        }else {
            Error(e?.message ?: e.toString())
        }
        trySend(res).isSuccess
    }
    awaitClose {
        snapListener.remove()
    }

}
```

and here is the content of my Response sealed class:

```
sealed class Response<out T> {
object Loading: Response<Nothing>()

data class Success<out T>(
    val data: T?
): Response<T>()

data class Failure(
    val e: Exception
): Response<Nothing>()
```

so basically, I see that my T? is what forces the cast to ANY, but I can't seem to shake it off. I also have Firebase Auth flow that uses it, so I can't really play with it without messing things up!

Can anyone give me advice, on what option(s) could be available to me in that situation?

Comment: What happens if you use `val res: Response<List<SettingBudget>> = //...`? Sometimes the compiler needs a little help and you can't fully rely on implicit type inference. By the way, did you mean to make the Success.data property nullable? I think it should probably be non-nullable, which will make it easier to work with the results.

Comment: It's already the type, the Response is my issue `T?` but like I said I can't change it

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Did you try specifying the type like I said? If so, what is the new error message? You should be able to use a non-nullable version with authentication by using Unit as the type when authenticating.

Comment: @AndreDesbiens Have you tried Tenfour04's suggestion?

Comment: Just did and it does not work. I get this from the Auth " AuthViewModel.kt: (27, 77): Type mismatch: inferred type is Response.Success<Nothing?> but Response<BeginSignInResult> was expected "

Comment: Found a workaround: I have created a third response with the type string and it solves it,no need to change the success. The only con to this workaround is I have to provide a useless ELSE to everything using Response and this way I can manage to have my output!thanks for your time @Tenfour04